# How to unit test coroutine when it contains coroutine delay?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

When I add a coroutine delay() in my view model, the remaining part of the code will not be executed.

This is my demo code:

```
class SimpleViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Unconfined

    var data = 0

    fun doSomething() {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            data = 1
        }
    }
}

class ScopedViewModelTest {

    @Test
    fun coroutineDelay() {
        // Arrange
        val viewModel = SimpleViewModel()

        // ActTes
        viewModel.doSomething()

        // Assert
        Assert.assertEquals(1, viewModel.data)
    }
}
```

I got the assertion result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start a coroutine which suspends for 1 second before setting `data` to 1. Your test just invokes `doSomething` but does not wait until `data` is actually being set. If you add another, longer `delay`, to the test it will, work:

```
@Test     
fun coroutineDelay() = runBlocking {
    ...
    viewModel.doSomething()
    delay(1100)
    ...
}
```

You can also make the coroutine return a `Deferred` which you can wait on:

```
fun doSomething(): Deferred<Unit> {
    return async {
        delay(1000)
        data = 1
    }
}
```

With `await` there's no need to delay your code anymore:

```
val model = SimpleViewModel()
model.doSomething().await()
```

Comment: Is there a way to not including the specific delay number in the test?

Comment: with async for example

Answer (score 3):

The first issue in your code is that `SimpleViewModel.coroutineContext` has no `Job` associated with it. The whole point of making your view model a `CoroutineScope` is the ability to centralize the cancelling of all coroutines it starts. So add the job as follows (note the *absence* of a custom getter):

```
class SimpleViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext = Job() + Dispatchers.Unconfined

    var data = 0

    fun doSomething() {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            data = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Now your test code can ensure it proceeds to the assertions only after all the jobs your view model launched are done:

```
class ScopedViewModelTest {

    @Test
    fun coroutineDelay() {
        // Arrange
        val viewModel = SimpleViewModel()

        // ActTes
        viewModel.doSomething()

        // Assert
        runBlocking {
            viewModel.coroutineContext[Job]!!.children.forEach { it.join() }
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(1, viewModel.data)
    }
}
```