# How do I run coroutines as blocking for unit testing?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I've begun writing unit tests for my MVP Android project, but my tests dependent on coroutines intermittently fail (through logging and debugging I've confirmed verify sometimes occurs early, adding `delay` fixes this of course)

I've tried wrapping with `runBlocking` and I've discovered `Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)` from `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test`, but trying so many combinations hasn't yielded any success so far.

```
abstract class CoroutinePresenter : Presenter, CoroutineScope {
    private lateinit var job: Job

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        job = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }
}

class MainPresenter @Inject constructor(private val getInfoUsecase: GetInfoUsecase) : CoroutinePresenter() {
    lateinit var view: View

    fun inject(view: View) {
        this.view = view
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        refreshInfo()
    }

    fun refreshInfo() = launch {
        view.showLoading()
        view.showInfo(getInfoUsecase.getInfo())
        view.hideLoading()
    }

    interface View {
        fun showLoading()
        fun hideLoading()

        fun showInfo(info: Info)
    }
}

class MainPresenterTest {
    private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("Mocked UI thread")

    private lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter
    private lateinit var view: MainPresenter.View

    val expectedInfo = Info()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)

        view = mock()

        val mockInfoUseCase = mock<GetInfoUsecase> {
            on { runBlocking { getInfo() } } doReturn expectedInfo
        }

        presenter = MainPresenter(mockInfoUseCase)
        presenter.inject(view)
        presenter.onCreate()
    }

    @Test
    fun onResume_RefreshView() {
        presenter.onResume()

        verify(view).showLoading()
        verify(view).showInfo(expectedInfo)
        verify(view).hideLoading()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }
}
```

I believe the `runBlocking` blocks should be forcing all child `coroutineScopes` to run on the same thread, forcing them to complete before moving on to verification.

Comment: Could you please provide code of your `Presenter` and complete code of test class.

Comment: @Sergey I've expanded my code samples as requested, I hope it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `CoroutinePresenter` class you are using `Dispatchers.Main`. You should be able to change it in the tests. Try to do the following:

1. Add `uiContext: CoroutineContext` parameter to your presenters' constructor:

   ```
   abstract class CoroutinePresenter(private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main) : CoroutineScope {
   private lateinit var job: Job

   override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
       get() = uiContext + job

   //...
   }

   class MainPresenter(private val getInfoUsecase: GetInfoUsecase, 
                       private val uiContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main 
   ) : CoroutinePresenter(uiContext) { ... }
   ```
2. Change `MainPresenterTest` class to inject another `CoroutineContext`:

   ```
   class MainPresenterTest {
       private lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter

       @Mock
       private lateinit var view: MainPresenter.View

       @Mock
       private lateinit var mockInfoUseCase: GetInfoUsecase

       val expectedInfo = Info()

       @Before
       fun setUp() {
           // Mockito has a very convenient way to inject mocks by using the @Mock annotation. To
           // inject the mocks in the test the initMocks method needs to be called.
           MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

           presenter = MainPresenter(mockInfoUseCase, Dispatchers.Unconfined) // here another CoroutineContext is injected 
           presenter.inject(view)
           presenter.onCreate()
   }

       @Test
       fun onResume_RefreshView() = runBlocking {
           Mockito.`when`(mockInfoUseCase.getInfo()).thenReturn(expectedInfo)

           presenter.onResume()

           verify(view).showLoading()
           verify(view).showInfo(expectedInfo)
           verify(view).hideLoading()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Re-architecting so the CoroutineScope was able to be mocked with `Dispatchers.Unconfined` worked as expected. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

@Sergey's answer caused me to read further into `Dispatchers.Unconfined` and I realised that I was not using `Dispatchers.setMain()` to its fullest extent. At the time of writing, note this solution is **experimental**.

By removing any mention of:

```
private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("Mocked UI thread")
```

and instead setting the main dispatcher to

```
Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
```

This has the same result.

A less idiomatic method but one that may assist anyone as a stop-gap solution is to block until all child coroutine jobs have completed (credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53335224/4101825):

```
this.coroutineContext[Job]!!.children.forEach { it.join() }
```